# Error 'type mismatch' when trying to use player GameObject on a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am a complete Unity beginner. For my first project I'm trying to do a zombie shooter. I got new enemies to spawn and a player and everything, but the enemy prefab I have isn't taking my player object in it's script 'inputs' for a character to chase. If I do put it in, it says 'type mismatch'. How do I fix this??

Enemy script

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f; // The speed at which the enemy moves
    public float stoppingDistance = 2f; // The distance at which the enemy should stop following 
    
    public GameObject target;

    void Start() {
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }
    private void Update()
    {

        if (transform.position.y <= -200) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if (target != null)
        {
            // Calculate the direction to the target
            Vector3 direction = target.transform.position - transform.position;

            // Check if the distance to the target is greater than the stopping distance
            if (direction.magnitude > stoppingDistance)
            {
                // Move towards the target
                transform.Translate(direction.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
                // Stop moving when close to the target
                // You can add additional logic here, such as attacking the target
        }
    }
}
```

Player script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float walkSpeed = 6f;
    public float runSpeed = 12f;
    public float jumpPower = 7f;
    public float gravity = 10f;
    public float lookSpeed = 2f;
    public float lookXLimit = 45f;
    public float defaultHeight = 2f;
    public float crouchHeight = 1f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 3f;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    private float rotationX = 0;
    private CharacterController characterController;

    private bool canMove = true;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);

        bool isRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        float curSpeedX = canMove ? (isRunning ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
        float curSpeedY = canMove ? (isRunning ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
        float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (forward * curSpeedX) + (right * curSpeedY);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canMove && characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpPower;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection.y = movementDirectionY;
        }

        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && canMove)
        {
            characterController.height = crouchHeight;
            walkSpeed = crouchSpeed;
            runSpeed = crouchSpeed;

        }
        else
        {
            characterController.height = defaultHeight;
            walkSpeed = 6f;
            runSpeed = 12f;
        }

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        if (canMove)
        {
            rotationX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried some things with nothing new and am completely clueless. Sorry if things in the script are messy or not necessary at all, I've been throwing everything at the wall to fix it and plan to polish after.

Comment: When posting a wall of code for others to debug for you, you might want to expedite the process by indicating *where* the error occurs.  Please visit the [help] and study [ask] for more tips and guidelines for using the site effectively.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure where it occurs.

Comment: How can an exception be thrown and you not know where? The exception tells you where it was thrown. You need to stop what you're doing and learn how to debug code. You then need to debug this code. You may well find and fix the issue yourself then. If you can't, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information. A lack of debugging information is one of the specific reasons available for voting to close a question.

Comment: *"it says 'type mismatch'"*. What is "it"? What actually happens? Is this a compilation error or a run time exception? You need to be specific about what actually happens. Vague descriptions mean that we either have to guess or we end up making assumptions that could be incorrect and end up wasting everyone's time.

Comment: A **prefab** is an **asset** living **persistently** in your Project View. Objects within your scene are **temporarily** loaded instances. If the scene is closed/unloaded they don't exist anymore! Therefor Unity's Inspector does not allow you to reference any scene objects in assets such as prefabs, `ScriptableObject`s, etc. .. only the other way round ... is that what happens here?

Answer (score -4):

If you're a beginner I would advise not asking questions here because people on here are typically quite rude to beginners. Though your question is a bit confusing still.

A "type" is like a gameobject, int, string, etc. It's a type of variable, what the variable being referenced is basically. So what's clearly happening is that wherever your error is happening that line is trying to assign an object of some kind to a variable type that does not match what the object is.

So specifically if the script is trying to assign a collider as a character controller variable or a gameobject as a character controller.

Also you're best off looking up "brackeys navmesh" tutorials especially if you really don't have much experience, because trying to code your own pathfinding will be frustrating. I see you're directly using the transform to move the npcs and that's a big nono. That causes a lot of problems.

I hope this helps.